# rspec error in Rails3: Formatter 'nested' unknown

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My tests were running fine, then suddenly I started getting this error whenever I tried to run rspec:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:167:in `find_formatter': Formatter 'nested' unknown - maybe you meant 'documentation' or 'progress'?. (ArgumentError)
```

I haven't made any changes to my .rspec file, which only contains one thing:

```
--color
```

I'm using the 'rspec-rails' gem.

I'm not sure what I did differently to get this error. I must have changed something... but what? I've never seen this error before and googling it was no help.

I'm a jr dev/recent grad and still learning, so any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you revert to a previous version where it works and find your differences?  The `nested` formatter was removed in the 3.0 betas, so something is specifying it somewhere.  Did you recently update to RSpec 3.0 after starting with 2.x?  Could also try grepping through your project for "nested".  Tools like [ack](http://beyondgrep.com) and [the_silver_searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) make it easy to do.

Comment: @NickVeys Thanks for the help! I reverted back to a previous version so that I can keep working, and I am going to try the grepping tools you suggested so that I can figure out this mystery. I'll post an update if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Change your .rspec file to `--color --format documentation`

Read more about the formatters by typing `rspec --help` in the console.